# I want to select the employees from my employees able (I named it ANGAJATI) who has the salary > avg(salary) of their department

Tags: sql

In the employees table I have id_departament
And I can`t figure it out how to extract the avg salary for every employee

Comment: Have a sub-query that returns each department avg-salary. JOIN.

Comment: Please add sample data along with whatever you may have already tried.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: How does an *employee* have an average salary?  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions if your RDBMS supports them:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, avg(salary) over(partition by id_department) avg_salary_dept
    from employee e
) t
where salary > avg_salary_dept
```

Alternatively, you can join the table with an aggregate query that computes the average salary per department:

```
select e.*
from employee e
inner join (
    select id_department, avg(salary) avg_salary_dept 
    from employee
    group by id_department
) a on e.id_department = a.id_department and e.salary > a.avg_salary_dept
```